# Google Analytics Data API script not working on google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am writing a script to export events with a certain name from GA and into Google Sheets, but I am running into an issue every time. All the time I am getting the

```
Info    Failed with error: undefined
```

Error and nothing I do does not seem to fix it.

When I copied the code the guide that is on [official docs page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analyticsdata?authuser=0), I got the same error.

This is the code I copied:

```
function runReport() {
  const propertyId = 'YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID';

try {
const metric = AnalyticsData.newMetric();
metric.name = 'activeUsers';

const dimension = AnalyticsData.newDimension();
dimension.name = 'city';

const dateRange = AnalyticsData.newDateRange();
dateRange.startDate = '2020-03-31';
dateRange.endDate = 'today';

const request = AnalyticsData.newRunReportRequest();
request.dimensions = [dimension];
request.metrics = [metric];
request.dateRanges = dateRange;

const report = AnalyticsData.Properties.runReport(request,
    'properties/' + propertyId);
if (!report.rows) {
  console.log('No rows returned.');
  return;
}

const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Google Analytics Report');
const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

// Append the headers.
const dimensionHeaders = report.dimensionHeaders.map(
    (dimensionHeader) => {
      return dimensionHeader.name;
    });
const metricHeaders = report.metricHeaders.map(
    (metricHeader) => {
      return metricHeader.name;
    });
const headers = [...dimensionHeaders, ...metricHeaders];

sheet.appendRow(headers);

// Append the results.
const rows = report.rows.map((row) => {
  const dimensionValues = row.dimensionValues.map(
      (dimensionValue) => {
        return dimensionValue.value;
      });
  const metricValues = row.metricValues.map(
      (metricValues) => {
        return metricValues.value;
      });
  return [...dimensionValues, ...metricValues];
});

sheet.getRange(2, 1, report.rows.length, headers.length)
    .setValues(rows);

console.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s',
    spreadsheet.getUrl());
 } catch (e) {
// TODO (Developer) - Handle exception
console.log('Failed with error: %s', e.error);
}
}
```

It always failed at the *AnalyticsData.Properties.runReport* part with the error mentioned above. My Google account has access to the GA property I put in the variable.

Comment: Note: This is an advanced service that must be enabled before use.  <-- did you do that

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I enabled the service in the left side menu.

Comment: Is your script using a [standard cloud project instead of default cloud project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects)? If yes, you need to enable the [Analytics Data API in the API Library](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/analyticsdata.googleapis.com) also. If this does not solve your problem, try to add `console.log(e)` right before the the existing `console.log` and you can find the error details.